# No rollback with spring mybatis mysql

Tags: mysql, spring, transactions, mybatis

I am stuck with the transaction in Spring.
I don't know why never do a rollback. 
Does anybody know what it is happening?

web.xml:

```
    <web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>Spring Security Application</display-name>

    <!-- Spring MVC -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>        
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-database.xml, /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

FileCabServiceImpl.java

```
@Service("FileCabService")
public class FileCabServiceImpl implements FileCabService
{
    @Autowired
    private FileCabMapper fileCabMapper;

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public void insertFileCab(FileCab fileCab) 
    {
        fileCabMapper.insertFileCab(fileCab);
        throw new NullPointerException(); // Error to do the rollback
    }
}
```

Controller.java:

```
@RestController
public class ReservationController 
{
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ReservationController.class);

    @Autowired 
    ReservationServiceImpl reservationService;
    @Autowired
    FileCabService fileCabService;
    @Autowired
    FileCounterService fileCounterService;
    @RequestMapping(value = "/api/reservation", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, method = RequestMethod.POST)

    public void reservationProcess()
    {
        FileCab fileCab = new FileCab();
        fileCab.setnUser("user");   
        fileCab.setiPax(5);
        fileCab.setnNamePax(""); 
        Date dateIn = new Date();
        fileCab.setdDateIn(dateIn);
        fileCab.setdDateOut(dateIn);
        fileCab.setnCodeRef("");
        int fileCounter = fileCounterService.getiFileCounterByYear(2017, 1);
        fileCab.setnTravelFile(String.valueOf(++fileCounter));
        fileCab.setiUserGroup(1);
        fileCab.setnYear(String.valueOf(Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR)));                
        fileCab.setdOpenDay(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());              
        fileCab.setiAgency(0);              
        fileCab.setnStatus("Cerrado");
        fileCab.setbPrePaid(0); 
        fileCab.setbPaid(0);
        fileCab.setdDatePrePaid(null); 
        fileCab.setDcPrePaidAmount(BigDecimal.ZERO);
        fileCab.setiTourService(0); 
        fileCab.setnObservations("");

        fileCabService.insertFileCab(fileCab);
    }
}
```

spring-database.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd"        
    default-autowire="byName">

    <context:annotation-config />

    <context:component-scan base-package="es.app.spring" />

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://xxx.xxx.xxxx.xxx:3306/spring_res?autoReconnect=true" />
        <property name="username" value="XXXXXX" />
        <property name="password" value="XXXXXX" />
    </bean>     

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
      <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
      <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
      <property name="typeAliasesPackage" value="es.app.spring.model"/>
      <property name="mapperLocations" value="classpath*:es.app.spring.mappers/*.xml"/>
    </bean> 

    <bean class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer">
      <property name="basePackage" value="es.app.spring.mappers" />   
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Any help will be appreciate.
Thank you

Comment: Let me guess your `mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml` also contains `<context:component-scan base-package="es.clickonline.resclick.spring" />`...

Comment: Yes, it's true, I'm sorry, it was a mistake when I copied to this post. I have changed and I tried again but the result is the same, no rollback. Thank you

Comment: Not sure what to make of that comment.; If you have `context:component-scan base-package="es.clickonline.resclick.spring" />` twice it will load all the beans twice one instance is proxied (and unused) and the other is not proxied and wil be used. As mentioned in multiple questions the root context should load anything but web related content (datasource, services, repositories etc.) and the dispacherservlet should load ONLY web related content (controllers, views etc.). Your component scan element has to reflect this.

Comment: Yes, that was the error. I had two <context:component-scan base-package="es.app.spring" /> in two differents files (spring-database.xml & mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml). Now I have divide this label, in one file, only scan controllers and in the other file, only scan services.
Thank you very much for your help.